# gdb: exit program without exiting gdb

Tags: c, windows, gdb, cygwin

I am debugging a program using gdb. First I `load` my executable, then I `continue` to run the program. I sometimes want to interrupt execution of my program, so I do `Ctrl + C`.

My problem is that this closes *both* my program and gdb. How can I exit my program without exiting gdb?

Comment: That isn't supposed to happen; Ctrl-C is just supposed to **interrupt** (not terminate) your program, and it's definitely not supposed to terminate gdb.  What environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cygwin. Weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like under Windows, you have to use `Ctrl-Break` not `Ctrl-C`. See this [page](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Cygwin-Native.html).

Excerpt:

> MS-Windows programs that call SetConsoleMode to switch off the special
>   meaning of the `Ctrl-C' keystroke cannot be interrupted by typing C-c.
>   For this reason, gdb on MS-Windows supports C- as an
>   alternative interrupt key sequence, which can be used to interrupt the
>   debuggee even if it ignores C-c.

Comment: Thanks. This still quits GDB. Now when it quits it writes "Quit (core dumped)"

Comment: @Randomblue Oh blimey - doesn't seem very happy does it.  I don't know what to suggest, other than switching to Microsoft compilers perhaps (they are free with the Windows SDK).

Comment: @Randomblue do you run the stuff from `cmd` or `sh` console? Is the debugged program Cygwin or Win32 native? (for the record: is `gdb` Cygwin or Win32? ;) )

Answer (score 40):

Have you tried to use `kill` from inside gdb?

Comment: Yes. But after `continue` I do not running to the gdb command prompt, so nothing happens.

Comment: How @trojanfoe said, Ctrl-C should just interrupt your program, so that you'll have again the gdb console. However, try to use `start` to start your program. The execution should stop at the beginning of `main` function. Then use `kill` to kill your program.

Comment: When I try `start` I get "No symbol table loaded.  Use the "file" command."

Answer (score 19):

Use ctrl-c to interrupt the application. Then run "signal SIGINT" from the GDB prompt, which will send this signal to your application, causing it to do the same things it would normally have done when you do ctrl-c from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

First run the program (not from inside gdb), then find its pid.

In another shell, run `gdb --pid=<your program's pid>`. This attaches gdb to a running program. It stops the program's execution, so issue `c` to continue.

Now quit your program, your gdb session will stay there.

Comment: My program is running on a remote host. (An ARM chip.)

Answer (score 4):

Like Manlio said, what you want in this case is `kill`, which will prompt you with a message that reads:

`Kill the program being debugged? (y or n)`

If you type `help running` you will see all the important commands you will need to know to do common things, such as stopping the execution of a current program. These should be all commands for the program you are running and not gdb.

[image: shell]