# With the NDK's gdb in Cygwin, how do I interrupt (break into) the debuggee

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin

I'm using the NDK on Windows, which means I have to run gdb from within cygwin in order to do native debugging.  It works, but there's one thing I can't figure out:

Once the debugger is attached and the process is running free (e.g., I gave gdb the "continue" command and there are no breakpoints), how do I interrupt the debuggee process?  My understanding is that for gdb in a normal Linux environment, you do this with Ctrl-c.  However in the Cygwin environment, this seems to kill (?) the gdb process.

Granted most people probably don't do NDK debugging in Windows, but it is supported...a debugger is nearly unusable if you can't break in asynchronously.  How is anyone able to debug?

Comment: Perhaps there is a reason you are choosing cygwin. Google has a [version of eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) which runs under windows with native windows versions of the unix tools, so everything runs under eclipse under windows. Under eclipse, the breakpoints are set in the eclipse GUI. Be sure not to put any spaces in directory names.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm confused though.  Are you saying when you download the Android SDK that native-code debugging in Eclipse should just work?  It doesn't seem too.

Comment: Or are you saying the NDK has some Eclipse plugin or something that allows native-code debugging from Eclipse?  Again, I don't see anything like that.

Comment: In the past, I've gotten Android native-code debugging in Eclipse to work by (more or less) following these instructions: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/.  But I'm worndering if they are out of date at this point...why can't the ADT include the C/C++ Eclipse plugin and anything else needed to facilitate native-code debugging on Android?

Comment: Yes, the google package has everything needed to do native developing and debugging inside eclipse. Just follow the install instruction, open up the test application, click a breakpoint and run as a native application and the breakpoint should just work. Be sure to avoid spaces in directory names. Be sure the c/c++ build properties include NDK_DEBUG=1. The launch will sometimes hang, but cancel and try again and it should launch. Repeated launch fails, reset adb in ddms or kill adb, cygpath, gdb in task manager.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I still don't quite get it.  Could you point me to the exact install instruction and test application you are talking about?  I don't see anything much in the NDK documentation or the ADT documentation about using Eclipse for developing/debugging native code.  Also I just tried: 1. Creating a new Eclipse Workspace, 2. Importing the hello-jni NDK sample app, 3. Running it as a Java application (I didn't see anything about running as a native application) 4. The app crashed because the native .so wasn't built or installed.

Comment: @DavidStone: after you have a Java project in ADT, go to project menu->Android->Add Native support. And when you want to debug native, use a different launcher - it's conveniently called "Debug As -> Android Native Application"

Comment: oops sorry, I just realized I posted the wrong link [http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) I'll still try to write up a better answer, but this should be what your looking for.

Comment: OK now I got it, thanks for your patience guys.  There are two main plugin groups for Android Development serverd from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.  "Developer Tools", which I had installed to do non-native Android development, and "NDK Plugins" which I did not have installed.

Answer (score 1):

gdb on MS-Windows supports <kbd>Ctrl-BREAK</kbd> as an alternative interrupt key sequence, which can be used to interrupt the debuggee even if it ignores <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd>. Doesn't this trick work for Android gdb, too?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "C-"

Comment: Oops, it was control-break, lost in copypaste on my phone.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669025/gdb-exit-program-without-exiting-gdb - ctrl-break does not resolve yhe problem for NDK, unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

When Cygwin on windows to run ndk-gdb, there isn't a way to interrupt the Android process to which gdb is attached.  Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break both quit gdb.